# An integration inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

> $f$ is differentiable on [-1,1], $M=\sup|f'|$. There is $a \in (0,1)$ such that $\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=0$. Prove that
>   $$
> \left|\int^1_{-1}f(x)dx\right| \le M(1-a^2)
> $$

I don't know how to use $\int^a_{-a} f(x) dx = 0$.

Comment: I bet what you use is $f(x)=f(x)-\frac1{2a}\int_{-a}^a f(t)\,dt=\frac1{2a}\int_{-a}^a(f(x)-f(t))\,dt$, then estimate $|f(x)-f(t)|$ using $|f'|\le M$.

Comment: some thoughts: we can write $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = \int_{-1}^{-a} f(x) dx + \int_a^1 f(x) dx$. Also, $f(x)$ must take on the value $0$ for some $x \in (-a, a)$, since if $f(x)$ was either strictly positive or strictly negative, then its integral over $(-a, a)$ could not be $0$. If $x_0$ is such an $x$, ie $f(x_0) = 0$, then we can get a bound $f(x) \leq M (x-x_0)$ for $x \geq x_0$, which may help in bounding one of the terms in the decomposition of $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx$ above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\left| \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \mathrm{d}x \right|=
\left|\int_{-1}^{-a} f(x) \mathrm{d}x  + \int_{a}^1 f(x) \mathrm{d}x\right| \\
\le \int_{-1}^{-a} |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_a^1 |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
As mentioned in the comments, $\int_{-a}^a f(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$ implies that $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in(-a,a)$, since if $f(x)$ was either strictly positive or strictly negative, then its integral over $(−a,a)$ could not be $0$. Let $x_0\in(-a,a)$ be the value of $x$ where $f(x_0)=0$. Then, as $\left\lvert f'(x) \right\rvert \le M$, we have that for every $x\in[-1,1]$,

$$|f(x)| =|f(x)-f(x_0)| \le M|x-x_0|.$$

Therefore
$$\int_{-1}^{-a} |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x\le M\int_{-1}^{-a} (x_0-x) \, \mathrm{d}x=M\int_a^1(x_0+x)\mathrm{d}x,$$
$$\int_{a}^{1} |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x\le M\int_{a}^{1} (x-x_0) \, \mathrm{d}x,$$

which gives us the bound

$$M\int_a^1(x_0+x)\mathrm{d}x+M\int_{a}^{1} (x-x_0) \, \mathrm{d}x=M\int_a^1 2x\mathrm{d}x=M(1-a^2).$$